# Django 1.7 Groups

Tags: django, django-orm, django-authentication

What would be the best method for altering the default group to include a foreign key to a company?

This is using the built - in auth, or would you create a custom auth?

To further update... I would like a many - to - many between groups and company and then a third table for user groups.  For example -- company groups (m2m) and user companygroups (m2m)

This will allow organizations to create their own groups if needed...

Comment: Why would including a foreign key have anything to do with a group ? If you are using django 1.5+, you can use the custom user profile

Comment: @karthikr we are building a Saas solution which will permit company's to create their own groups and assign users to those groups.  We would like to use a FK on the groups table to track which company the group(s) belong to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to create a m2m between the company table and groups table